# How to pass value of one input to Multiple input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multi input field like below

```
  <td width="25%">
     <input name="interest"  id="interest" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%
<input name="interest1"  id="interest1" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%1
..................
</td>
```

Now I want pass same value of one input field to other four input fields? how I will pass ? any idea ?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in My  previous design have single input field its  fields show interest value.Now new UI design four interest input fields have ? i want pass  same value single input fields multiple input fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try this.,

```js
$("#interest").change(function(){
  $('.myinput').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="interest"  id="interest" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%
<input name="interest1"  class="myinput" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%1
<input name="interest2"  class="myinput" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%2
<input name="interest3"  class="myinput" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%3
<input name="interest4"  class="myinput" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />%4
```

Comment: thank you sathish i have used already used class for design purpose .its possible add two class single input fields ?

Comment: bro how to use name for instead of class?